# Click event for dynamically created array of buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application i have array of buttons created dynamically.I am trying to raise an onclick event for those buttons and change the text of the button which i click.I tried the below code for this but its not working.How can i do this?.Any suggesions?

**Code**:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        lbl = new Button[5];
        lbl[i] = new Button();
        lbl[i].Text = "hi";
        lbl[i].Width = 30;
        lbl[i].Click += new EventHandler(lbl_click);
        //lbl[i].CssClass = "label";
        div1.Controls.Add(lbl[i]);
    }
```

**Click Event**:

```
   protected void lbl_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    Button[] lbl = sender as button[];
    lbl[i].Text = "clicked";

   }
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? You're recreating the button array from scratch both in your `Click` handler and in every iteration of the loop in your first code snippet. (Your edit only fixed the first problem.)

Comment: You'll have to define your for loop on OnInit event of page life cycle

Comment: Ah, and your edit also introduced another problem: `sender` is a `Button`, not a `Button[]`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi i tried steve's answer it works in pageload but not inside a method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are recreating the array of buttons in your event handler, but this array is not populated with the buttons created before. It is empty and will give you a null reference exception if you try to use an element of this array (`null.Text`, it will never work).
The sender object instead, represent the button that the user has clicked.

```
protected void lbl_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Button lbl = sender as Button;
     lbl.Text = "clicked";
}
```

Also, if you need to know which specific button has been clicked then I suggest you to add something to differentiate between them at creation time:

For example use the name property:

```
Button[] lbl = new Button[5];
for(int i = 0; i< 5; i++)
{
    ....
    lbl[i].Name = "Button_" + i.ToString();
    ....
}
```

Notice that I have moved the array declaration and initialization outside the loop that create every single element of the array (the actual button).

Comment: if i use this in pageload its working.but if i use it inside a method then the event is not firing.

Comment: Take a look at the `Related` column on the right. There are numerous questions on this problem.

Comment: I saw that.It tells controls should be created only on page load.Is that true.We cannot create it anywhere else?

Comment: Sorry, I can't really help on this because I am not an expert on ASP.NET. Perhaps a new question on the specific matter could catch the interest of new people on this

Comment: check this i have asked another question on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738693/button-click-event-for-array-of-buttons-not-firing